# Navigation in HTML5

Tags: css, html

```
.box:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     left: 43%;
     top: 30%;
     margin-top: -18px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 40px;
     border-color: transparent transparent transparent **rgba(7, 17, 241, 1);**    
}

/*html*/
<a href="abc.html" target="_blank"><div class="box"></div></a>
```

I used the above CSS arrow to navigate into another html page, but as I have given `<href>` it is opening in new tab. But my requirement is to navigate in current tab only. Please do suggest..

Comment: remove `target="_blank"` . not a css problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `target="_blank"` from your link. It has nothing to do with CSS.

```
<a href="abc.html"><div class="box"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The target attribute defines how the link should be opened. In your existing case `_blank` means it will open in a blank new window, or tab.

You can remove it entirely, and it will open the link in the same window or tab that you're already using.

```
<a href="abc.html">
```

Read this for the different ways you can open links - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_target.asp